# Functional and not so juicy open-chat for my site?

Tags: php, css, chat, livechat

I'm looking for a functional and simple chat for my site where users will be able to discuss. I'm not talking about a client chat, but an open one where everyone will be able to write, smile... Those chats that have channels... My site is Wordpress, but I don't particularly like the chat plugins that are provided. Also, most are paid and quite heavy. Is there a chat like the Iflychat plugin or Chatwee that is a separate system and built into the site? In bootstrap I found a lot of ready-made chat systems, but none is what I'm looking for. I will be happy if someone can help with what I need as a chat and provide method to install it correctly. Sorry for my lack of ability on that matter.

Comment: We don't do recommendations, as mentioned in the [help/on-topic]

Comment: It's to much to ask for all the code to build one, that's why i thought it's better to ask for something that exist and can be modified.

Comment: We don't do either of those things though - both are off-topic, for different reasons. Read the link I gave to see why we don't give recommendations. See also [ask].

Comment: What you're supposed to to is ask a focused question about a specific issue within what you're trying to implement

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.